# PointerEvent error when compile flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, signature

I am facing an error when I try to use [signature: ^3.2.0 pub](https://pub.dev/packages/signature). I am running the where flutter pub reference as [example](https://pub.dev/packages/signature/example)
The error message is:

```
Compiler message:
file:///C:/DartSRC/dartSRC1.2/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/signature-3.2.0/lib/signature.dart:81:22: Error: The getter 'localPosition' isn't defined for the class 'PointerEvent'.
 - 'PointerEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('file:///C:/DartSRC/dartSRC1.2/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'localPosition'.
    Offset o = event.localPosition;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///C:/DartSRC/dartSRC1.2/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/signature-3.2.0/lib/signature.dart:210:10: Error: Getter not found: 'kIsWeb'.
    if (!kIsWeb) {
         ^^^^^^
file:///C:/DartSRC/dartSRC1.2/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/signature-3.2.0/lib/signature.dart:210:10: Error: The getter 'kIsWeb' isn't defined for the class 'SignatureController'.
 - 'SignatureController' is from 'package:signature/signature.dart' ('file:///C:/DartSRC/dartSRC1.2/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/signature-3.2.0/lib/signature.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'kIsWeb'.
    if (!kIsWeb) {
         ^^^^^^
Compiler failed on C:\oeu\projeler\Flutter\ProjectName\lib\main.dart
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

And my flutter doctor -v is:

```
C:\oeu\projeler\Flutter\ProjectName>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139], locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at C:\DartSRC\dartSRC1.2\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (1 year, 8 months ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code (version 1.49.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Android Studio (not installed) issue is a common bug but it is installed.